# How can I print a lists in different lines

Tags: python

I am trying to create a board for the Noughts and Crosses game with a List matrix, but I can not order every list in differents lines in 3x3 raw and columns, can somebody help me please?

```
''' 
board = [
[ "|_|","|_|","|_|"],
["|_|","|_|","|_|"],
["|_|","|_|","|_|"],  
]

print (board)

'''
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I'd suggest storing only the actual game state in `board` (i.e. whether it's a Nought, Cross, or empty, using single characters or even numbers) and not those decorative `_` and `|`. Those should be added in some `print_board` function.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a helper function called something like `print_current_board` where you use [str.**join**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) to print each row with tabs between the row's cells:

```
def print_current_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print('\t'.join(row))

board = [
    ["|_|", "|_|", "|_|"],
    ["|_|", "|_|", "|_|"],
    ["|_|", "|_|", "|_|"],
]

print_current_board(board)
```

**Output:**

```
|_| |_| |_|
|_| |_| |_|
|_| |_| |_|
```

Comment: Instead of `' '.join`, you can also just do `print(*row)`, this will automatically print the elements of `row` separated by spaces, as would `print(row[0], row[1], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#You can use End in Print statement:-
def print_current_board(board):
    for row in board:
        for i in row:
            print(i,end='')
        print('')

board = [
    ["|_|", "|_|", "|_|"],
    ["|_|", "|_|", "|_|"],
    ["|_|", "|_|", "|_|"] ]

print_current_board(board)
```